# Exit with code 1 due to network error: HostNotFoundError in Python

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf, pdf-conversion

I am trying to convert HTML to pdf and I am using "wkhtmltopdf"

code is as follows

```
import pdfkit
path_wkhtmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)

urls= ['https://www.amazon.com/','https://www.google.com/']
pdfkit.from_url(urls, 'out.pdf', configuration=config)
```

It was working fine and suddenly I am getting this error

```
Exit with code 1 due to network error: HostNotFoundError
```

What should I do to avoid this error.